# what is name of this transition effect?

Tags: css-transitions, effect

This is the link http://codecanyon.net/item/estro-jquery-ken-burns-swipe-effect-slider/full_screen_preview/235111

What is the effect name of image transition in that slider? And how to achieve it? Is it zoom in and moving the image at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

The name of that effect is Keb Burns (or Pan and Zoom effect). 
I don't think you can achieve it only with css-transitions. You should use some JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [example](http://dabblet.com/gist/3763579). You should `background-poistion,background-size` properties to get it. I hope the example code is helpful to get it.

and tutorial on [background properties](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/).

moving background is based on `background-position`.

changing the image require jquery.